# onchange event not working

Tags: javascript, html, dom

The onchange event is not working in the following code. I have a select tag and I would like to display a text box if the 'Yes' option is selected. When I select 'Yes' the text box does not appear.

Code:

```
<script type = "text/javascript">
            function showfield(name) {
                if (name == "Yes") {
                    document.getElementById("div1").innerHTML = '<input type = "text" cols = "10" rows = "9" name = "yes" />';
                } else {
                    document.getElementById("div1").innerHTML = "";
                }
            }
</script>

<select name = "Prior_Knowledge" class = "user" id = "prior_knowledge" onchange = "showfield(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value);">
            <option> </option>
            <option value = "1">Yes</option>
            <option value = "2">No</option>
</select>
<div class = "user" id = "div1"></div>
```

Comment: Your values are 1 & 2, not `Yes`..   IOW:  `if (name == "1")` maybe.

Comment: You need to replace `"Yes"` with `1`. You need to compare the `value` of your `option` tag, not the inner HTML.

Answer (score 2):

The value of the option `Yes` is actually `"1"`, not `"Yes"`.

```html
<script type = "text/javascript">
            function showfield(name) {
                if (name == "1") {
                    document.getElementById("div1").innerHTML = '<input type = "text" cols = "10" rows = "9" name = "yes" />';
                } else {
                    document.getElementById("div1").innerHTML = "";
                }
            }
</script>

<select name = "Prior_Knowledge" class = "user" id = "prior_knowledge" onchange = "showfield(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value);">
            <option> </option>
            <option value = "1">Yes</option>
            <option value = "2">No</option>
</select>
<div class = "user" id = "div1"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```js
var priorKnowledge =  document.getElementById("prior_knowledge");

priorKnowledge.addEventListener("change", function() {
    if(this.options[this.selectedIndex].text == "Yes"){
      document.getElementById("div1").innerHTML = '<input type = "text" cols = "10" rows = "9" name = "yes" />';
    }else{
    document.getElementById("div1").innerHTML = "";
    }
});
```

```html
<select name = "Prior_Knowledge" class = "user" id ="prior_knowledge">
  <option> </option>
  <option value = "1">Yes</option>
  <option value = "2">No</option>
</select>
<div class = "user" id = "div1"></div>
```

Or your original code

```html
<script type = "text/javascript">
            function showfield(name) {
                if (name == "Yes") {
                    document.getElementById("div1").innerHTML = '<input type = "text" cols = "10" rows = "9" name = "yes" />';
                } else {
                    document.getElementById("div1").innerHTML = "";
                }
            }
</script>

<select name = "Prior_Knowledge" class = "user" id = "prior_knowledge" onchange = "showfield(this.options[this.selectedIndex].text);">
            <option> </option>
            <option value = "1">Yes</option>
            <option value = "2">No</option>
</select>
<div class = "user" id = "div1"></div>
```

Change `this.options[this.selectedIndex].value` in `this.options[this.selectedIndex].text`

Comment: Works great! Thanks!

Comment: If it helped you, make the right answer to help those in need, but it was a pleasure